# php num_rows greater than 0

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

In an effort to update old code and learn at the same time, I've become lost. I'm not sure if I got this right, I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction instead of bashing my newbness. I know to move away from mysql statements which is why I'm trying to move into the oop and learn it as I go. Not sure if I should use the

```
if($rs->num_rows > 0)
```

or if it should be

```
if($rows_returned > 0)
```

The following is what I'm hoping is a decent start, the original is at the bottom.

```
<?
// functions.php is required to connect to the database as usual
require("db.inc.php");

//our sql statement
$sql1 = 'select * from flights where flightnumber='" . $_REQUEST['DATA2'] . "'');
$rs=$conn->query($sql1);
if($rs == false) {
trigger_error('Wrong SQL:' . $sql1 . ' Error:' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}else {
$rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
if ($rs->num_rows > 0 ){
    for ($i=0$i<$num_result;$i++)
    {

$rs->data_seek(0);
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '1|flightplan\n';
    echo $row['departure'] .'\n';
    echo $row['destination'].'\n';
     ....more echo's removed to save reading.....
}
}
else{
echo '0|Flightnumber not found';
}

/* original kept as guide for updating
 *
 * $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `flights` where flightnumber="".$_REQUEST['DATA2']."'");
 * $num_result = mysql_num_rows($query);
 * if ($num_result > 0)
 * {
 *  for ($i=0;$i<$num_result;$i++)
 *  {
 *      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
 *      echo "1|flightplan\n";
 *      echo $result['departure']."\n";
 *      echo $result['destination']."\n";
 *    ....more echo's removed to save reading.....
 *  }
 * }
 * else
 * {
 *  echo "0|Flightnumber not found";
 * }
 */
 ?>
```

Comment: Firstly, you should clean up your `$sql1` variable, It's invalid. Also, both are correct, but you could keep your code clean and concise by using the first option - `if($rs->num_rows > 0)`

Comment: After going through some of the code some more, I found that I would need to keep with the $rows_returned. Cause right after, I failed to realize that ($i=0;$i<$num_result;$i++) has to be changed to match. I can't believe I missed that. Also, the $_REQUEST['DATA2'] is to read what the users app sends.

Answer (score 0):

Your second answer is correct. If you're getting data from a query object that you want to use later, it's strongly recommended to store the data in a new variable. That way, when you release the query object you don't lose the data.

Good luck coding!